# How to bind table data to Drop Down List?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to bind tblState data to the Drop Down list but data can not bind.
I get the error like

> DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property
>   with the name '@StateName'.

**Store Procedure for get State**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetStates
as
select * from tblState
```

**source**

```
public DataTable GetStates()
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("GetStates", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

**aspx page**

```
Property p = new Property();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        FillStates();
    }
}

private void FillStates()
{
    ddlState.DataSource = p.GetStates();
    ddlState.DataTextField = "@StateName";
    ddlState.DataValueField = "@Sid";

    ddlState.DataBind();
    ddlState.Items.Insert(0, "Select State");
}
```

Comment: why `@StateName`? Without @ like `StateName` should be perfectly fine

Comment: Thank you sir,  error solved

Answer (score 1):

I think you are giving procedure parameters name(@statename) instead of column names.You should set datatextfield and valuefield properties as same column name which your datatable contains returned by procedure.